# Trying to identify my Armstrong bicycle

Tags: wheels, handlebars

[image]Can anyone tell me what model Armstrong this bicycle is and possibly what year thank you

Comment: That saddle may be slightly painful to ride as is.

Comment: Hard to nail down.  Can't tell whether the front hub is a brake, a generator, or something else.  The crank is a bog-standard cottered unit, which basically places is between about 1930 and 1975.  The frame is quite "modern", meaning it could be between maybe 1930 and 1990.  But I gather the Armstrong bike brand slowly disappeared in the 60s.

Comment: @MaplePanda - Not if you're a hard-ass!

Comment: @DanielRHicks agreed - the frame looks astonishingly modern - shows how little changed from the 1930s to the 1980s.  The front fork rake and head tube angle show it is older, with laid-back angles like that, but the rear triangle looks quite 80s and "normal"

Comment: Not sure if it’s the perspective but the fork looks bent. Combined with the mis-aligned handlebars it looks like it suffered an accident.

Comment: @Criggie - I wonder how far back that reflector bracket goes.  I wouldn't expect to see that on a bike prior to about 1950.

Comment: @DanielRHicks the front bracket is for a light.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a lot like this Armstrong
[image]
The seat stay bolted to the seat tube may be one difference.

[Based on the conversation in the thread...](https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/653281-armstrong.html)

> this model is a 1953 so the rear hub tells me

If your bike does have a Sturmey Archer three speed hub you may be able to date the bike by the markings on the hub.

[Hub Date Marks – How Old Is Your Sturmey Archer Hub?](https://colwoodwheelworks.co.uk/sturmey-archer/sturmey-archer-hub-date-markings/)

> Hubs after World War 2
> From 1947 to 2000 Sturmey Archer clearly marked their hubs with a date. This hub date marking will show the last two figures of the year and the month.

The article goes on to explain how to date older SA hubs.

[Here is the 1950 Armstrong catalog](http://threespeedhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Armstrong-Catalog-Poster-1950-UK.pdf).
This picture looked to me like a good match
[image]
Three speeds and dynamo hubs were offered as an option

[Other Armstrong catalogs](http://threespeedhub.com/catalog-category/armstrong/)